# Alter observable state quick while waiting for backend response

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement a toggle button and I don't know how to approach this specific scenario with Observables.
To prevent delay between user click and having an actual response from backend, I was thinking I could, **beforehand**, change it to the new state. Then when backend comes with the update, keep the backend update as source of truth.

On the dom side I'm using async pipe.

ButtonComponent side:

```
this.isButtonActive$ = this.buttonService.isButtonActive$();
```

DOM side:

```
<span *ngIf="isButtonActive$ | async">
    ... 
</span>
```

From Service side:

```
   public isButtonActive$(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.currentState$.pipe(
            map((state) => state.isActive)
        );
   }
```

This would work fine as soon as I get new data from the backend, it would listen to this currentState$ changes and receive the new value.

But if the backend takes 2-3 seconds to update, it would create a bad user experience.

The idea would be to as soon as the user clicks on the button, it would immediately change its state to the new one, doesn't matter if it fails for now or not, backend will tell and update accordingly.

If this were promises, it would be easy to tackle for me, but how can I manage this behavior with Observables? Am I forced to use a BehaviorSubject?

Thanks.

Comment: Observables can be used similar to a Promise. Just subscribe to it. `this.buttonService.isButtonActive$().subscribe(value => this.isButtonActive$ = value)`

Comment: Mmmm i see, but should i then put it straight into the toggle functionality, otherwise this would be the same as waiting for backend. Right?

Comment: There's multiple ways to do it. I would likely call the observable in the TS file and change the HTML to `<span *ngIf="isButtonActive$">`. Yes. It could be similar to calling an API backend. Where the observable gets the data doesn't really matter. It's an async operation either way.

Comment: *ngIf="isButtonActive$" without async pipe??

Comment: Yes. My assumption is that `isButtonActive$` is a boolean value. Therefore async doesn't apply. When the observable returns with the result, that resulting value is mapped to `isButtonActive$` which will trigger the UI to update.

Comment: Nono, isButtonActive$ is of type `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting you change

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how `this.currentState$` is populated, but here something we tried for the API calls.

```
public markActive() {
  return this.http.post('myAPIURL', body).pipe(
    startWith({
      // object you want to set while API call is in progress.
    });
  );
}
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith

Comment: Good idea actually, but in my case, the startValue would be like !currentValue when clicked on toggle button. Seems there's no way to get the current value so we could pass it to startWith :(

Comment: you should be able to do the same in the component where you have your state. Instead of writing startWith in the service you can write it in the component. `this.myService.markActive().pipe(startWith({/*object*/})).subscribe(...)`

Comment: yes, you can pass a custom object/primitive to `startWith` but i would need to pass current value of the button so I can just negate currentValue to simulate it was already stored on backend.